# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||

Tags: javascript, php

Below is my registration form, further down is the Javascript function. However when the Register button is clicked nothing happens, Inspected the element and found an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||.

```
                <form method="post" id="regForm" name="regForm" onSubmit="RegisterMember(); return false">
                    <h1>Become a member</h1>
                    <div id="formPane">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username *" name="username" id="username" value="" required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password *" id="password" name="password"  value='' required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname *" name="fullname" id="fullname"  value='' required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Valid Email *" id="email" name="email"  value='' required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" placeholder="phone *" id="phone" name="phone" required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Referral Link" name="upliner" id="upliner" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Bitcoin Address" id="bitcoin" name="bitcoin" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" placeholder="Bank Name *" name="bank" id="bank" required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Number *" id="accountNumber" value='' name="accountNumber" required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" placeholder="Branch Code" name="branchCode" id="branchCode" /> 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Account Holder *" name="accountHolder" id="accountHolder" value='' required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value= ''class="form-control" placeholder="Address *" name="address" id="address" required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" value='' class="form-control" placeholder="City *" id="city" name="city" required />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
                        <?php
                        foreach($page->getCountries() as $country)
                            $page->display('<option value="'.$country.'" '.($country=="Nigeria" ? 'selected' : '').'>'.$country.'</option>');
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                     <div><br>
                        <table cellpadding=""><tr>
                            <td valign="top"><div class="captcha" id="captchaHolder"><?php $page->display($captcha);?></div></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CAPTCHA" id="captcha" name="captcha" required /></td>
                        </tr></table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn btn-default submit" onClick="RegisterMember()" href="#cc">Register</a> 
                        <div id="LoaderPane"></div>
                        <a class="reset_pass" href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="separator">

                        <p class="change_link">Already a member?
                            <a href="../login.php" class="to_register"> Login </a>
                        </p>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <br />

                    </div> 
                </form>
```

```
   // JavaScript Document 
var PageRel="";
function DoLogin()
{
    var username = document.loginForm.username.value;
    var password = document.loginForm.password.value;
    var OCaptcha = document.getElementById("captchaHolder").innerHTML;
    var Captcha = document.loginForm.captcha.value;
    var loaderPane = "LoginStatus";
    if(Captcha!=OCaptcha)
    {
        document.getElementById(loaderPane).innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Invalid security code.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(username.length== 0 || password.length== 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(loaderPane).innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>You must enter your credentials.</span></div>';
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById(loaderPane).innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {           
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.search('success') > -1)     
            { 
                var rootUrl = xmlhttp.responseText.split(':')[1];
                document.getElementById(loaderPane).innerHTML ='<div class="message-success"><span>Login was successful.</span></div>';
                if(rootUrl=="member")
                    window.setTimeout("window.location='member/?option=home'", 2000);
                else                    
                    window.setTimeout("window.location='admin/index.php?option=home'", 2000);
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(loaderPane).innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</span></div>';                    
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", PageRel + "action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("SignIn=true&username=" + username +"&password="+ password+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function ChangePassword()
{
    var username = document.pswdForm.txtUsername.value;
    var password = document.pswdForm.txtOldPassword.value;
    var npassword = document.pswdForm.txtNewPassword.value;
    var npassword2 = document.pswdForm.txtNewPassword2.value;
    if(npassword!=npassword2)
    {
        document.getElementById("statusReport").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>New passwords do not match.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(password.length== 0 || npassword.length== 0 || npassword2.length== 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("statusReport").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>You must enter your passwords.</span></div>';
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("statusReport").innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {           
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.search('success') > -1)     
            {  
                document.getElementById("statusReport").innerHTML ='<div class="message-success"><span>Password changed successful.</span></div>';  
                document.pswdForm.reset();          
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("statusReport").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</span></div>';                    
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("changepassword=change&username=" + username +"&password="+ password+"&npassword="+npassword+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function RegisterMember()
{ 
    var Username = document.regForm.username.value;
    var Name = document.regForm.fullname.value; 
    var Password = document.regForm.password.value;  
    var Country = 'Nigeria'; //                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 document.regForm.country.options[document.regForm.country.selectedIndex].value;
    var City = document.regForm.city.value;            
    var Email = document.regForm.email.value;   
    var Phone = document.regForm.phone.value;   
    var Address = document.regForm.address.value;   
    var Bitcoin = document.regForm.bitcoin.value;
    var Upliner = document.regForm.upliner.value;
    var Bank = document.regForm.bank.value;
    var AccountNumber = document.regForm.accountNumber.value;
    var BranchCode = document.regForm.branchCode.value;
    var AccountHolder = document.regForm.accountHolder.value;
    var OCaptcha = document.getElementById("captchaHolder").innerHTML;
    var Captcha = document.regForm.captcha.value;
    document.getElementById("LoaderPane").style.display= "block";
    if(Username.length < 5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Your username must not be less than 5 characters.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(AccountNumber.length !== 10)                                                
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Account Number Must be 10 digits.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(Phone.length !== 11)                                                
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Phone Number Must be 11 digits.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(Password.length < 5)
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Your password must not be less than 5 characters.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(Name.length== 0 || Bank=="" || || City.length== 0 || Email.length== 0 ||Address.length== 0 || Captcha.length== 0 || 
    OCaptcha.length== 0 || AccountHolder=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>You must fill all the field marked in asterisks.</span></div>';
        return;
    }
    else if(false)//OCaptcha != Captcha)
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Invalid security code.</span></div>';
        document.regForm.captcha.value = "";
        document.regForm.captcha.focus();
        return;
    } 
    document.getElementById("formPane").style.display= "none";

    document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {           
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.search('___success___') > -1)       
            { 
                document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML ='<div class="message-success"><span>Congratulation! You have registered you can now login and don\'t forget to activate your account,the activation mail has sent to your email (Please check your Spam folder). Click the activation link to activate you account. <a href="../login.php">CLICK HERE TO LOGIN</a></span></div>';
                //window.setTimeout("window.location='activation.php'", 5000);
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</span></div>';
                document.getElementById("formPane").style.display= "block";                     
            }
        }

    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("register=true&username="+Username+"&fullname="+Name+"&password="+Password+"&country="+Country+"&city="+City+"&email="+Email+"&phone="+
                                Phone+"&address="+Address+"&bitcoin="+Bitcoin+"&upliner="+Upliner+"&bank="+Bank+"&accountNumber="+AccountNumber+
                                "&branchCode="+BranchCode+"&accountHolder="+AccountHolder+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function ActivateAccount()
{ 
    var Code = document.regForm.activationCode.value;
    var TNumber = document.regForm.turingNum.value;
    var OTNumber = document.regForm.matchingTuring.value; 
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").style.display= "block";
    if(TNumber != OTNumber)
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Invalid turning number.</span></div>';
        document.regForm.turingNum.value = "";
        document.regForm.turingNum.focus();
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("formPane").style.display= "none";

    document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.search('success') > -1)     
            {    
                document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML ='<div class="message-success"><span>Account has been activated successfully. You can now login.</span></div>'; 
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</span></div>';
                document.getElementById("formPane").style.display= "block";                     
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("activate=true&code=" + Code+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function CreateVIPAccount()
{
    var Name = document.vipForm.vip_name.value;
    var Bank = document.vipForm.vip_bank.value;
    var AccountNumber = document.vipForm.vip_acc.value;
    var Bitcoin = document.vipForm.vip_bitcoin.value;
    var Phone = document.vipForm.vip_phone.value;
    var Email = document.vipForm.vip_email.value;
    var Username = document.vipForm.vip_username.value; 
    if(Username.length < 5)
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>Your username must not be less than 5 characters.</span></div>';
        return;
    }

    else if(Name.length== 0 || Bank=="" || Phone.length== 0 || AccountNumber.length== 0 || Email.length== 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>You must fill all the field marked in asterisks.</span></div>';
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {           
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.search('___success___') > -1)       
            { 
                document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML ='<div class="message-success"><span>VIP Account has been created successfully.</span></div>';
                document.vipForm.reset();
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("LoaderPane").innerHTML= '<div class="message-error"><span>'+xmlhttp.responseText+'</span></div>';
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("addvip=true&&name="+Name+"&bank="+Bank+"&acc="+AccountNumber+"&bitcoin="+Bitcoin+"&phone="+Phone+"&email="+Email+
                 "&username="+Username+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function ProcessBuySell(refNo)
{
    document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML= document.getElementById("process").innerHTML; 
    var Status = document.getElementById("status-"+refNo).value; 
    var Type = document.getElementById("type-"+refNo).value; 
    var xmlhttpProcess = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpProcess=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpProcess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpProcess.readyState==4 && xmlhttpProcess.status==200)
        {
            if(xmlhttpProcess.responseText.search('success') > -1)      
            {    
                document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML =''; 
                document.getElementById("c1-"+refNo).innerHTML =Status; 
                document.getElementById("c2-"+refNo).innerHTML =Status; 
                document.getElementById("c3-"+refNo).innerHTML =Status; 
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML= 'failed';                      
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttpProcess.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpProcess.send("processBuySell=true&refNo=" + refNo+"&status="+Status+"&type="+Type+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}
function ProcessExchangeOrder(refNo)
{
    document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML= document.getElementById("process").innerHTML; 
    var Status = document.getElementById("status-"+refNo).value; 
    var xmlhttpProcess = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpProcess=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpProcess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpProcess.readyState==4 && xmlhttpProcess.status==200)
        {
            if(xmlhttpProcess.responseText.search('success') > -1)      
            {    
                document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML =''; 
                document.getElementById("c1-"+refNo).innerHTML =Status; 
                document.getElementById("c2-"+refNo).innerHTML =Status;  
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML= 'failed';                      
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttpProcess.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpProcess.send("processExchangeOrder=true&refNo=" + refNo+"&status="+Status+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function ProcessWithdrawayOrder(refNo)
{
    document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML= document.getElementById("process").innerHTML; 
    var Status = document.getElementById("status-"+refNo).value; 
    var xmlhttpProcess = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpProcess=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpProcess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpProcess.readyState==4 && xmlhttpProcess.status==200)
        {
            if(xmlhttpProcess.responseText.search('success') > -1)      
            {    
                document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML =''; 
                document.getElementById("c1-"+refNo).innerHTML =Status; 
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("process-"+refNo).innerHTML= 'failed';                      
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttpProcess.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpProcess.send("processWithdrawalOrder=true&refNo=" + refNo+"&status="+Status+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function VerifyMember(mid)
{
    document.getElementById("process-"+mid).innerHTML= document.getElementById("process").innerHTML; 
    var xmlhttpProcess = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpProcess=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpProcess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpProcess.readyState==4 && xmlhttpProcess.status==200)
        {
            if(xmlhttpProcess.responseText.search('success') > -1)      
            {    
                document.getElementById("process-"+mid).innerHTML =''; 
                document.getElementById("ver-"+mid).innerHTML ="Verified"; 
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("process-"+mid).innerHTML= 'failed';                        
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttpProcess.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpProcess.send("verifyMember=true&mid=" + mid+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function LoadInbox(inboxId)
{
    document.getElementById("inboxDetails").innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader3").innerHTML; 
    var xmlhttpProcess = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpProcess=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpProcess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpProcess.readyState==4 && xmlhttpProcess.status==200)
        {
            if(xmlhttpProcess.responseText.search('success') > -1)      
            {    
                document.getElementById("inboxDetails").innerHTML =xmlhttpProcess.responseText; 
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("inboxDetails").innerHTML= '';                      
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttpProcess.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpProcess.send("inbox=true&qid=" + inboxId+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function ConfirmVIPPayment(phmid, nth)
{
    document.getElementById("cbutton_"+nth).style.display="none"; 
    document.getElementById("cpane_"+nth).innerHTML= document.getElementById("loader3").innerHTML; 
    var xmlhttpProcess = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttpProcess=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttpProcess = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttpProcess.readyState==4 && xmlhttpProcess.status==200)
        { 
            if(xmlhttpProcess.responseText.search('success') > -1)      
            {    
                document.getElementById("cpane_"+nth).innerHTML="Confirmed"; 

            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("cpane_"+nth).innerHTML="<font color='red'>Failed</font>";  
                document.getElementById("cbutton_"+nth).style.display="inline-block";               
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttpProcess.open("POST","../action/process.php",true);
    xmlhttpProcess.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttpProcess.send("confirmPayment=true&phmid=" + phmid+"&rand="+Math.random()*100,true);
}

function DeleteInbox(qid)
{
    if(window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this message.?"))
        window.location="index.php?option=inbox&delete=true&qid="+qid;
}

function RejectInputAmount(txtObj, mn, mx)
{
    if(txtObj.value.length>0)
    {
        if(isNaN(txtObj.value))
            txtObj.value="";
        else if(eval(txtObj.value) < eval( mn))
        {
            alert("PH Amount must not be less than " + mn);
            txtObj.value = "";  
        }
        else if(eval(txtObj.value) > eval( mx))
        {
            alert("PH Amount must not be greater than " + mx);
            txtObj.value = "";  
        }
    }
}

function RejectNaNAmount(txtObj)
{
    if(txtObj.value.length>0)
    {
        if(isNaN(txtObj.value))
            txtObj.value="";
    }
}

var thisTimer=0;
var seconds=0;
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;

function setTimer(secs)
{  
    thisTimer=secs;
    hours = Math.floor(secs/3600);
    minutes = Math.floor((secs-(3600*hours))/60);
    seconds = (secs-(3600*hours)) % 60;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =PadTimeZero(hours) + ":" + PadTimeZero(minutes) + ":" + PadTimeZero(seconds); 
}
function Countdown()
{
    if(seconds==0 && hours==0 && minutes==0){
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
        window.location.reload();
    }
    else
    {
        --thisTimer; 
        hours = Math.floor(thisTimer/3600);
        minutes = Math.floor((thisTimer-(3600*hours))/60);
        seconds = (thisTimer-(3600*hours)) % 60;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =PadTimeZero(hours) + ":" + PadTimeZero(minutes) + ":" + PadTimeZero(seconds);
    } 
}

function PadTimeZero(tm)
{
    if(tm<10)
        return "0" + tm + "";
    return tm;
}   
function LaunchProofForm(mid,phmid,name,bank,acc)
{
    document.getElementById("ph_mid").value = mid;
    document.getElementById("ph_phmid").value = phmid;
    document.getElementById("ph_name").value = name;
    document.getElementById("ph_bank").value = bank;
    document.getElementById("ph_acc").value = acc;
    document.getElementById("phlauncher").click();
}

function LaunchProof(mid,phmid,name,bank,acc, evlink)
{
    document.getElementById("vname").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("vbank").innerHTML = bank;
    document.getElementById("vacc").innerHTML = acc;
    document.getElementById("vlink").innerHTML = "<a href='"+evlink+"' target='_blank'>View Evidence</a>";
    document.getElementById("vphmid").value = phmid;
    document.getElementById("phlauncher2").click();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 pairs of or's at line 139. remove one of those

```
else if(Name.length== 0 || Bank=="" || || City.length== 0 || Email.length== 0 ||Address.length== 0 || Captcha.length== 0 ||  OCaptcha.length== 0 || AccountHolder=="")
```

Comment: My since apologies,

Comment: The initial Javascript i Uploaded it wrongly, can you kindly revise? :-)

Comment: Heres the error  ::: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||
VM1417 register.php:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: RegisterMember is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM1417 register.php:103)

Comment: Solved it. Thanks

Comment: @NdiokweluZubby please accept the answer if it help :)